# How to display index page without login/register on Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication, laravel-7

I'm making a website in Laravel 7 and it was working fine. Then, I enable authentication and now it wouldn't let me go to index page. It keeps displaying default registraion form on index page. I even changed the content of **resources\views\auth\register.blade.php** but it displays default registration form on index page. I don't know what to share here, whether content of some file or file structure or something. Please tell me what to share here and I'll edit my question.

This is my routes file.

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');

Route::get('/whiteboard', 'PagesController@whiteboard');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that you put your index route behind auth middleware, check your route setting

Comment: share your routes

Comment: you are trying to access pages controller's index??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Yes.

Comment: check whether the controller has auth middleware in it's constructor method.

Comment: comment this line  `$this->middleware('auth');` from HomeController's `_constructro`.